# ZSH auto-completion help not triggering for custom command options beginning with "--"

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, autocomplete, tab-completion

I often use the `gencomp` command with [RobSis's](http://github.com/RobSis) [`zsh-completion-generator`](http://github.com/RobSis/zsh-completion-generator) to generate ZSH completion definitions, and it works great for the most part! There is, however, *one small caveat* that I have noticed.

**The Issue:**

For commands with options that are prefixed with dashes (**e.g.** "`subl --new-window`"), pressing tab will only trigger completion options if you have typed the command *and* at least one dash character (**e.g.** press `TAB` after typing "`subl -`").

**My Question:**

Anyone know how I can get the tab completions to show up before typing a dash (**e.g.** press `TAB` after typing "`subl` ")?

---

See below for an example of the `compdef` file contents for one of these completion definitions - in this case, it's for Sublime Text's `subl` command:

```
#compdef subl

# zsh completions for 'subl'
# automatically generated with http://github.com/RobSis/zsh-completion-generator
local arguments

arguments=(
    '--project[Load the given project]'
    '--command[Run the given command]'
    {-n,--new-window}'[:  Open a new window]'
    {-a,--add}'[:         Add folders to the current window]'
    {-w,--wait}'[:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning]'
    {-b,--background}'[:  Dont activate the application]'
    {-s,--stay}'[:        Keep the application activated after closing the file]'
    {-h,--help}'[:        Show help (this message) and exit]'
    {-v,--version}'[:     Show version and exit]'
    '--wait[implied if reading from stdin. Use --stay to not switch back]'
    '*:filename:_files'
    )

_arguments -s $arguments
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot answer this question, but IMHO this is the regular behaviour of the _zsh_ completion system. I'm also not sure how you want to tell the shell whether you want to complete an option or a file name?!(Different keybindings might do...)

Comment: I suppose if you want to complete a filename, you could prefix it with `./` (or provide the full/relative path) 